How can I solve an issue related to my slug file?
I'm encountering an issue in my Next.js project with the following structure: under the warehouse directory, there are 3 items: index.tsx, [...Slug].tsx,  and inventory( which is a folder), within the inventory folder there exist index.tsx and [...slug].tsx files. The problem arises specifically within the [...slug].tsx file located in the inventory folder, where all fetch requests are returning undefined. Strangely, the same fetch requests function properly when used in the top-level [...slug].tsx file under the warehouse directory. the fetch requests behave differently depending on their location within the project structure
Note: all imports, routes, urls etc... are correct the problem is specifically related to the location of the fetch
I wanted to send a fetch request I was expecting a response but instead I am getting undefined

[...some-name].tsx is a cath-all dynamic route, which means it will match all of the below:

/warehouse/box
/warehouse/box/tape
/warehouse/inventory
/Warehouse/inventory/tape
...and so on and so on.
This means that your /warehouse/inventory/[...slug].tsx will never run as /warehouse/[...slug].tsx catches all of the requests incoming to /warehouse/inventory/[...slug].tsx.

